# after updading classes Prestashop not working

Tags: prestashop

I

I have backup the classes files, after uploading them back, i get this error:

Fatal error: Class 'Address' not found in /home/**________**/classes/Cart.php on line 540

website is not opening....

Why this happens, I upload old files back and the same error.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

did you delete cache/class_index.php file after upload classes? 
There is part of readme_override.txt file:
Q: I added an override file but it seems to be ignored by PrestaShop
A: You need to trigger the regeneration of the /cache/class_index.php file. This is done simply by deleting the file. It is the same when manually removing an override: in order to reinstate the default behavior, you must delete the /cache/class_index.php file.

So, maybe Prestashop uses old cache

Regards